# Laravel problem when doing a query with sum and count

Tags: laravel

hello I was trying to take data and also the sum and the count of 2 columns this is the query that I am using

```
   $acept['acept']= DB::table('detail_proposal')
                ->join('proposal','proposal.pro_id','=','detail_proposal.pro_id')
                ->join('home','home.home_id','=','detail_proposal.home_id')
                ->select('home.home_nom','home.home_img',home.home_price,'proposal.pro_id','proposal.int_date')
                ->where('users.usu_id','=',$id)
                ->where('proposal.estate_id','=',2)
                ->selectRaw('count(proposal.pro_id) as Total','SUM(home_price)')
                ->get();
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "home.home_nom" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT.....
```

I know there is a problem with my query, how can I modify it to have the data I want to obtain?

Comment: Would you mind sharing migrations and some relationship mappings ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to add groupBy if you want to use aggregate function in select clause

```
 $acept['acept']= DB::table('detail_proposal')
                ->join('proposal','proposal.pro_id','=','detail_proposal.pro_id')
                ->join('home','home.home_id','=','detail_proposal.home_id')
                ->select('home.home_nom','home.home_img',home.home_price,'proposal.pro_id','proposal.int_date')
                ->where('users.usu_id','=',$id)
                ->where('proposal.estate_id','=',2)
                ->selectRaw('count(proposal.pro_id) as Total','SUM(home_price)')
                ->groupBy('home.home_nom')
                ->groupBy('home.home_img')
                ->groupBy('proposal.int_date')
                ->get();
```